# python: getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, valueerror, fclose

I have an issue with my code. I am trying to replace a pattern un a file. First I have an error on the number of opening files because I forgot to close my file. 
But now, I had f.close() into my code and I have the following error:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Here you may find a part of my code. Someone has an idea of what is wrong ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import shutil
from tempfile import mkstemp

infile = 'test_file.txt'
year  = int('2009')
month = int('1')
day   = int('10')

#################################################################################
def sed(pattern, replace, source):
    """
    Reads a source file and writes the destination file.
    In each line, replaces pattern with replace.
    Args:
        pattern (str): pattern to match (can be re.pattern)
        replace (str): replacement str
        source  (str): input filename
    """
    fin = open(source, 'r')
    fd, name = mkstemp()
    fout = open(name, 'w')
    for line in fin:
        out = re.sub(pattern, replace, line)
        fout.write(out)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()
    shutil.move(name, source) 

#################################################################################
def main():
    """
    Replace all year-month-days which have a possible wrong pattern
    """
    for i in range (6):
        for j in range (12):
            for k in range (22):
                Year = year + i; Month = month + j; Day = day + k
                pattern = '%s %s%s' %(Year, Month, Day)
                replace = '%s %s %s' %(Year, Month, Day)
                sed(pattern, replace, infile)

#################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

###### END
```

Thank you a lot.

Comment: What happens if you use a context manager instead?

Comment: Are you sure there are no indentation error in your original program?

Comment: like : with open (infile) as f ?

Comment: there is no indent error (i  am working with invisible in my editor, to be sure)

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us what your `sed` function is?

Comment: Yes of course. I am doing that right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as another answer because, well, it's clearly different.

Since you have an issue with your `sed` function opening too many files, I tried writing something that opens files as few times as possible. Moreover, you said that the file you want to edit is pretty big, so I avoided reading it directly into memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

input_file = 'test_file.txt'
output_file = 'result_file.txt'

def main():
  pattern = r"(\d{4}) (\d{1,2})(\d{2})"
  replace = r"\1 \2 \3"
  with open(input_file, "r") as inp:
    with open(output_file, "w") as oup:
        for line in inp:
          sub = re.sub(pattern, replace, line)
          oup.write(sub)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you incorrectly use your `sed` function. You open the file you want to edit inside your `main` function, and then it is opened again (and then closed) inside the `sed` function.

It looks like your `sed` function is supposed to be used on an entire file, not just a line.

If you edit your `main` function to something like that, it should work (if not, comment what's wrong):

```
def main():
    """
    Replace all year-month-days which have a possible wrong pattern
    """
    occurrences = 999 # arbitray number. If you know the exact number, you may want to edit this.
    for i in range (6):
        for j in range (12):
            for k in range (22):
                Year = year + i; Month = month + j; Day = day + k
                pattern = '%s %s%s' %(Year, Month, Day)
                replace = '%s %s %s' %(Year, Month, Day)
                sed(pattern, replace, infile, count=occurrences)
```

Comment: ok thanks, it makes sens. Can you explain me why are you deleted the 3 loops on i, j and k?

Comment: @OcéF I am sorry, I thought the loops were used to loop over lines so I erased them, but I re-read your code and understood their function. I will edit the code.

Comment: Thanks. I do not no the number of occurrences. It is a big file. And it doesn't work... I still have the same issue : OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files:

Comment: @OcéF Weird. It seems that the `sed` function should be closing all files it is opening. By any chance, is there another part of your script that is opening files? You may want to check how is `infile` declared or maybe how is the `main` function called.

"Worst" case scenario, you will have to write your `sed` anew ^^

Comment: That's really weird. I don't understand. I do not call it in another place. I changed the sed function, trying to make it simple, but I still have the same issue. I edited my code again.

Comment: I think the issue maybe because the sed fonction is in a loop. But I don't know how to do differently

Comment: @OcéF It may be the issue but I don't think it is. For every `open` there is a `close` inside that function, so the concurrent number of open files shouldn't be raising. I'll try writing a function that does the substitution you need, and post it in another answer.

Comment: @OcéF Can you confirm that all months and days are made of 2 digit? Meaning, january is written as `01` and not simply `1` (and same for days)?

Comment: As an example, I have "2014 1231" and I would like "2014 12 31".
Really thanks to think about it. I really do not understand what is wrong...

Comment: And it is a simply 1 or 2 or 8 and not 01, 02 or 08

Comment: @OcéF Okay. Can you confirm that all days are at least 10?

Comment: Yes, because I haven't this use with lower number:
```2008 8 5 1532```
```2009 818 1529```
```2010 311 0052```
And my lines are longer as :
```2010 311 0231 41.9 L -14.770 166.544 35.0 VAN 3 0.1 2.2LVAN 1```